# Clearing JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am making a program in which there is a square that changes its x and y positions when a key is pressed. The square moves but the the old square is still there. How do I remove/clear everything from a panel before I repaint it? Calling `removeAll` had no effect.

Comment: Please provide some code snippet, there are only few people here which can read someone's mind ;) Do you use Swing, AWT or maybe other framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably your code includes custom `paintComponent()` logic. The key thing to observe is what does your panel look like when you *do not* override `paintComponent()`? An empty (or cleared) panel:

Thus the solution is to invoke the `paintComponent()` method of the parent type on the panel, before executing your custom `paintComponent()` logic:

```
public class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // first draw a clear/empty panel
    // then draw using your custom logic.
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it working thanks. I had paintComponents not paintComponent

Comment: Overriding paintComponent() is the way to go, although to be fair the question did mention a Panel, not a JPanel. Its up to the OP to be more specific when posting a question.

Comment: downvoted. will remove downvote when poster corrects his answer and uses paintComponent instead of paint.

Comment: @user268396 please edit your post and change 1) public void CustomPanel extends JPanel {...} to the  public void CustomPanel extends Panel {...} painting for AWT Component  2) change paint() to the paintComponent for painting in Swing JComponent 3) thank you

Comment: Actually I had assumed that the original scenario meant that the whole panel would/should be painted anyway (regardless). On balance however it is probably best to stick with “best practice” here: paintComponent() will work fine as well.

Comment: @User268396: why should it matter if the "whole panel" should be painted? That is what paintComponent is for. It is exceedingly rare that someone is going to want to override the painting of borders or children. Anyway, thanks for the edit: Downvote removed, upvote given.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
g.clearRect (0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
```

Also, you could keep the old location of the square and just clear that rather than clear the whole background.

Comment: -1, Don't use getGraphics on a Swing compoent to do custom painting. This painting is only temporary and will be lost the next time a component paints itself. Custom painting is done in the paintComponent() method of a Swing component.

Comment: @camickr voted for your comment before reading the answer <g> - doing so, cant find a getGraphics ... was it edited without any traces?

Comment: I added the Graphics definition for clarity on what g was, I should've just had the method definition for paintComponent. @camickr was right so I did a minimal edit.

Comment: @kleopatra, I think you have 5 minutes to edit your answer after posting without any revision history.